# Merging SQL entries

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a problem.

I have this MySQL Table:

```
id | name | subid
1  | Joe  | 5
2  | Carl | 6
3  | Bob  | 7
4  | Joe  | 8
5  | Carl | 9
```

and I want to merge it like this:

```
id | name | subids
1  | Joe  | 5,8
2  | Carl | 6,9
3  | Bob  | 7
```

Is this possible? 
I have a realy big database and if I do this with a PHP-Cronjob, it would take  weeks...

Comment: Check out [group_concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for `group_concat()`:

```
select min(id) as id, name, group_concat(subid) as subids
from table t
group by name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Merging the rows is definitely possible with `GROUP BY` and [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat). However, this would replace one problem with another, perhaps even bigger problem. If anything, you should split the table, rather than merging it.

Create two tables - one for users and another one for user sub-ids. Populating the two would be very easy, and you would have a nicely normalized schema in the end.

```
CREATE TABLE USER_SUBID (USER_ID int, SUBID int);

CREATE TABLE NEW_USER (ID int, NAME varchar(20));

INSERT INTO NEW_USER (ID, NAME)
SELECT MIN(Id) as ID, NAME
FROM OLD_USERS
GROUP BY NAME

INSERT INTO USER_SUBID (USER_ID, SUBID)
SELECT MIN(Id) as USER_ID, SUBID
FROM OLD_USERS
GROUP BY NAME, SUBID
```

This would make two tables with the data as follows:

```
NEW_USER:
ID Name
-- ----
1  Joe
2  Carl
3  Bob

USER_SUBID:
USER_ID SUBID
------- -----
1       5
1       8
2       6
2       9
3       7
```

Comment: @dasblinkenlight . . . Interesting.  I interpreted "merge" as being output only.  I do agree with you that you should not store the data in the database using comma-delimited lists and your approach is the better approach for storing the data.